# SWIG, py + C: no attribute under pointer

Tags: python, c, swig

I have a strange problem with SWIG ( C + python )

In C, I have a function that returns pointer to struct `elements_t`. I call the functon in python, get the result ( the pointer) but I cannot access the elements of the structure..

```
typedef struct elements elements_t;
struct elements {
    int nelements;
    // ... other stuff
};

elements_t* get_elements()
{
    elements_t* p;
    // ...
    return p;
}
```

And in python I do:

```
r = clibrary.get_elements()
print r
# <Swig Object of type 'elements_t *' at 0xb77029f8>
print r.nelements
# AttributeError: 'SwigPyObject' object has no attribute 'nelements'
```

So I get the last error that there is no `nelements`, even though the `p` points to a proper structure...

Comment: yes, error in the question.  the code still does not work :(

Comment: Ok, and since r is a pointer to the struct, is it possible to just return the struct? I'm looking at section "31.3.6 Structures" at http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Python.html and there are some examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [pointers](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Python.html#Python_nn18) section of the SWIG for Python docs:

> The only thing you can't do is dereference the pointer from Python.

You would need to dereference that pointer to access its members. You'll need to write accessor/mutator functions in C to manipulate the struct members.

Comment: Or return just an instance of the struct instead of a pointer to it if it can be avoided..

Comment: The real reason is lacking declaration in the interface file of the "struct elements". So swig didn't produce the proxy class for the struct.  After adding declaration, you shall see:print r
#proxy of <Swig Object of type 'elements_t *' at 0xb77029f8> then you can access r.nelements

Comment: @bestwolf1983 do you mean appending `struct elements;` to the interface file?  I just tried.  It doesn't work.  Maybe I misunderstand.

Answer (score 0):

It's not pretty, but you can always write accessor functions that allow you to work with the pointer.